# Is there any automatic way to change multiple Mac Calendar events from a <xxx time zone> to a <floating> event?

Tags: calendar, timezone

I'm using Mac's Calendar under Catalina. As a pilot, I fly amongst so many time-zones so often, I've been using Calendar with Time Zone turned off, keeping everything on my local (body) time, no matter where I am. This includes my Mac (no automatic time zone update under System Preferences>Date & Time). Personally, this setup has worked great for me. Any event entry would automatically show up as e.g. "Dentist   12:00" or Departure    19:30".

However I somehow made an error (probably playing around with the System Pref's Date & Time time zone tab recently) which made all my Calendar entries now show my local time zone to the right of the actual set time , e.g. "12:00 CET", or "19:30 CEST" (having just changed to Summer time in Europe). Apart from taking up a big chunk of the limited line display in a Day event in the Monthly view, it's just outright annoying as I already KNOW what time zone the event is in – MY time.

My problem is I cannot seem to turn this off anymore. The only way to get rid of the CET/CEST is to change each and every entry I have manually into a floating event. With some 20 years of events on record, I was wondering if there is an app or script that will allow me to change any event automatically into a floating event.

Any help much appreciated!